# MultiLanguage Support for Vanilla Javascript application

Tags: javascript, jquery, multilingual

I have a Web Applicaiton written in Pure Javascript. We are doing lot of DOM manipulations using jQuery.

We are not using any third party packages and not even Node JS and want to have this app in simple pure Javascript.

During the development we have hardcoded many String directly in the HTML like below

```
 <div id='empName' class="empClass">Employee Name</div>

 <div id='depName' class="depClass">Dep Name</div>
```

Most of the app contains like above.

We are now looking for a way to support it for **MultiLanguage**, How can I convert my existing app to support multilanguage.

Below is the approach I am thinking of

- I did my research and planning to construct a JSON file for each
  language,
- Have seperate CSS file for each language and load
  dynamically

Is the above approach correct ?

How can I do the interpolation here like in the DIV InnerHTML I want to give the json Object value ? How could this be done

The html files are in separate View folder and how could I place the json object values to the elements in html files

Comment: If the respective divs all have an ID and all contain just the text, you can use a JSON file with keys like `"empName": "Name des Angestellten"` and just iterate over Object.entries() and replace.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is your markup generated initially?

Answer (score 0):

create a language sentence array, and use indexing and grouping by local under each key

```js
const langauge = (key, local) => {
  const sentances = {
      "hello" : {
        "en": "Hello",
        "fr": "bonjour",
      }
  }
  return sentances[key][local] || "";
}
```

the you could do this in js

```js
let local = "en";
let hello = langauge("hello", local);
```

or in html inline

```html
 <div id='empName' class="empClass"><script>document.write(langauge("hello", "en"))</script></div>
```

#### example usage

```
const langauge = (key, local) => {
  const sentances = {
      "hello" : {
        "en": "Hello",
        "fr": "bonjour",
      }
  }
  return sentances[key][local] || "";
}

let hello_en = langauge("hello", "en");
let hello_fr = langauge("hello", "fr");

console.log(hello_en, hello_fr);
```

[image]

### Test online

you may test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h85m0zjy/)